All NDVI Samples over period
I'm trying to extract a dictionary of every single NDVI sample in a given area for a given year.
import ee 
import numpy as np

ee.Initialize()

point = [29.548087060269182, 34.88359141968356]
area = point.buffer(250).geometry()

# define the image
img = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1').filterDate('2014-03-01', '2014-03-02').filterBounds(point)

median_data = img.mean()

# get the lat lon and add the ndvi
latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().addBands(median_data)

# apply reducer to list
latlon = latlon.reduceRegion(
  reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry=area,
  scale=250);

return latlon

Output:
{'DayOfYear': 15.040983606557377,
 'DetailedQA': 2116,
 'EVI': 643.1103825136612,
 'NDVI': 1020.7486338797816,
 'RelativeAzimuth': 7164.687978142077,
 'SolarZenith': 5346.90218579235,
 'SummaryQA': 0,
 'ViewZenith': 1942.6699453551914,
 'latitude': 29.548087060269182,
 'longitude': 34.88359141968356,
 'sur_refl_b01': 1913.4333333333336,
 'sur_refl_b02': 2349.391256830601,
 'sur_refl_b03': 925.6426229508199,
 'sur_refl_b07': 2950.762841530055}

Until now, my solution has been to iterate over every single day and if there is a result, record it.
Is there a way to do this in a batch?
I.e. given a year, return the desired output for all NDVI samples, without the need to check every single possible date if there is a sample?

Welcome to GIS community. I am not sure if I have  understood it right. For example if filterDate is as follows filterDate('2014-03-01', '2014-06-20'), it will return a new ImageCollection that only contains images captured within the specified date range. There is no need to check every day within this date range.

You were not very specific in the output you're looking for. Here's one potential approach you can take, that hopefully gets you closer to where you want to get.

Create an image collection for your year
Map over it and remove clouds
Map over the resulting image collection and extract the NDVI for your area, and turn the image into a feature. (I split the mapping upinto two steps, so I can put the masked images on a map and inspect them.)
Filter out features that doesn't have an NDVI.

At this point, it all depends on what you want to do. You can export the feature collection as a CSV file for instance.
scale = 250
point = ee.Geometry.Point([-72.9905664605981, 42.73362798150045])
area = point
# If you only want a single pixel from your point, you don't need to buffer
# .buffer(250)


def maskImage(image):
    return image.select("NDVI").updateMask(image.select("SummaryQA").Not())


def reduceRegion(image):
    ndvi = image.reduceRegion(
        reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(), 
        geometry=area, 
        scale=scale
    )
    return ee.Feature(None, ndvi).set("date", image.date().format("yyyy-MM-dd"))


collection = (
    ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13Q1")
    .select(["NDVI", "SummaryQA"])
    .filterDate("2014-03-01", "2015-03-01")
    .filterBounds(point)
    .map(maskImage)
)

timeSeries = (collection
    .map(reduceRegion)
    .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(["NDVI"]))
)
print(timeSeries.getInfo())


Amazing!!! Thank you!
Can you please explain how to add the latitude & longitude from the image, and not from the point, so I could ensure the image is approximately the same area?

What you did yourself works fine - add the NDVI band to pixelLonLat() before you run reduceRegion()

Thank you very much!
